# SQL sum() over() equivalent in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with total sales, month and year provided. I want to add 2 new rows that sums the sales value by month and year. Below is a snapshot of the data I have:

df

```
    Sales     Month Year
1   89825870    1   2017
2   248494100   1   2017
3   216344700   2   2017
4   209009300   3   2017
5   204138200   3   2017
6   12456789    1   2018
7   109876543   1   2018
```

The above data shows sales values as recorded over different months in different years.

Below is an example of the data I wish to obtain:

df

```
    Sales     Month   Year  Tot Sales/Month  Tot Sales/Year
1   89825870    1     2017  338319970        967812170
2   248494100   1     2017  338319970        967812170
3   216344700   2     2017  216344700        967812170
4   209009300   3     2017  413147500        967812170
5   204138200   3     2017  413147500        967812170
6   12456789    1     2018  122333332        122333332
7   109876543   1     2018  122333332        122333332
```

As you can see, the new column `Tot Sales/Month` records sum of sales groupby Month and Year (Month 1 and Year 2017, sum of sales will be recorded and will be same for all rows where Month is 1 and Year is 2017 and so on) and column `Tot Sales/Year` does the same but just for Years.

I know this code is easily procurable in SQL using window functions, but I am confused on how to do it on pandas.

What I have tried is shown below:

```
df.groupby('Month','Year')['Sales'].sum()
df.groupby('Year')['Sales'].sum()
```

The above 2 codes do give me the values I need, but how do I store these values as columns in the same dataframe ?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `df['Tot Sales/Year'] = df.groupby('Year')['Sales'].tranform('sum')`.

Comment: The trick here is to use `transform` which gives back an equal length factor as your original data and thus not aggregated. For example: `df['Tot Sales/Month'] = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['Sales'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Btw, [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html) has an extensive part where examples are given with comparisons to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work for your expected result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[89825870, 1, 2017],
[248494100, 1, 2017],
[216344700, 2, 2017],
[209009300, 3, 2017],
[204138200, 3, 2017],
[12456789, 1, 2018],
[109876543, 1, 2018]],columns=["Sales", "Month", "Year"])

df["Tot Sales/Month"] = df.groupby(["Month", "Year"])["Sales"].transform("sum")
df["Tot Sales/Year"] = df.groupby("Year")["Sales"].transform("sum")
```

Then the result would be:

```
>>> df
       Sales  Month  Year  Tot Sales/Month  Tot Sales/Year
0   89825870      1  2017        338319970       967812170
1  248494100      1  2017        338319970       967812170
2  216344700      2  2017        216344700       967812170
3  209009300      3  2017        413147500       967812170
4  204138200      3  2017        413147500       967812170
5   12456789      1  2018        122333332       122333332
6  109876543      1  2018        122333332       122333332
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use transform to get the columns you want like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([('89825870', '1', '2017'), ('248494100', '1', '2017'), ('216344700', '2', '2017'), ('209009300', '3', '2017'), ('204138200', '3', '2017'), ('12456789', '1', '2018'), ('109876543', '1', '2018')], columns=('Sales', 'Month', 'Year'))
df["Sales"] = df["Sales"].astype(np.int)

df["sales/month"] = df.groupby(["Month", "Year"]).transform("sum")
df["sales/year"] = df.groupby("Year")["Sales"].transform("sum")
df
```

Comment: I believe first sentence doesn't work. Result is following error: "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1"

Comment: Its working for me, can you try this full example seperately

Comment: Well, now that you placed the code to define the dataframe your whole code works. Not sure though why your code to create the "sales/month" columns is not working for the dataframe I defined in my answer. Stil wondering if it may be related on how you set the dataframe.